# Segmentation Fault with dirent struct

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, dirent.h

I'm writing a small client/server C program. A funciton in the client will be used to ask for the names of all regular files in a directory in the server. The server will return the file names as a char array over TCP. My program has many choices which can be run individually any numner of times and switched between easily. When I try to run the function to get the file names, I get s segmentation fault and don't know why. I have pasted my client and server code below.

Server:

```
void dir_details(int socket) {
    //Set up appropriate variables
    char StringArray[1024];
    struct dirent *de;
    struct stat st = {0};

    //If the upload directory doesn't exist, create it
    if (stat("upload", &st) == -1) {
        mkdir("upload", 0777);
    }

    //Opening the upload directory to be read
    DIR *dr = opendir("upload");

    if (dr == NULL) {
        printf("Could not open directory.");
    }

    //Add each file name to a char array
    while ((de = readdir(dr)) != NULL) {
        strcat(StringArray, de->d_name);
        strcat(StringArray, "\n");
    }

    closedir(dr);
    size_t n = sizeof(StringArray);
    //Send the char array back to the client
    writen(socket, (unsigned char *) &n, sizeof(size_t));   
    writen(socket, (unsigned char *) StringArray, n);   
    strcpy(StringArray, "");
    free(de);
}
```

Client:

```
void dir_details(int socket) {
    //Set up char array to be received form the server
    char dirdetails[5000];
    size_t k;

    //Receive char array from the server
    readn(socket, (unsigned char *) &k, sizeof(size_t));    
    readn(socket, (unsigned char *) &dirdetails, k);

    //Print the array to the client
    printf("%s\n", dirdetails);
}
```

Comment: You aren't storing the result of `malloc()`.

Comment: I've edited my post to remove it, that was just a temperary meausre to try and find the problem.

Comment: Change your work habits. Adopt a very incremental workflow. And spend a week reading books about programming. Your program is so buggy that you should destroy it, spend several days reading more, and start again from scratch. There is a bug about every other line in your code above, so it is not worth keeping it. Just delete your source file above and start again (after spending days reading more).

Comment: Your code is incomplete; in particular, it seems to be missing a `main()` function and at least one `#include`. Please [edit] your code so it's a [mcve] of your problem (including any necessary inputs, but preferably not needing any), then we can try to reproduce and solve it. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 3):

Read *carefully* [readdir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html). In practice, `struct dirent`'s last member `d_name` could behave as a [flexible array member](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member), even if it might not be exactly documented as such.

Your `StringArray` is likely to have a [buffer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow) (and you don't check that carefully enough). You forgot to zero it (at least with a `memset(StringArray, 0, sizeof (StringArray));`...)

Of course, you are misunderstanding [malloc](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc). It can fail, and you always need to use its result. Read more about [C dynamic memory allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation).

Read [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Compile with all warnings and debug info, so with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` if using [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/).

Spend several days reading more about basic C programming. Read some [C tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/). Look into some [C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) site. When in doubt, check the C11 standard [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) after having read some good tutorial on C programming. Study the source code of small [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) programs for inspiration.

After having improved your basic C programming skills, read something about Linux programming, e.g. [ALP](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/).

**Destroy your non-sense program** (it is so buggy that it is not worth improving it or try salvaging it). **Once you improved your C programming level, start writing again your program from scratch.** Use a good version control system (I recommend [git](https://git-scm.com/)), and do some very [iterative and incremental development](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_and_incremental_development) (write one or two dozen lines, compile them with all warnings, improve them to have no warnings, test them with your [GDB debugger](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/), and then commit them to your version control, and repeat all). Read carefully the documentation of *every* function you are using (e.g. `man` pages like [read(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html), [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html), [errno(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html), [printf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html), etc...)

NB. You probably should spend at least a whole week reading before touching your keyboard. I actually recommend reading [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/) (an excellent introduction to programming, which does not use C but teaches very important and relevant concepts)

Comment: And, from that same readdir documentation, do not attempt to free the return.